# Mostrar datos de tablas relacionadas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Quería consultarles lo siguiente: tengo una pequeña aplicación en laravel 5* en la cual tengo un par de tablas relacionadas (una tabla tb_activos con su id 'id_act' y un campo 'id_ubic') y una tabla ubicación (con su id 'id_ubic' para relacionarlo con la otra tabla) puedo insertar sin problemas y mostrar datos de la tabla activos también, pero al querer mostrar un dato de la tabla ubicación no me muestra nada ni me arroja error alguno.

Tengo los siguientes códigos:

en mi controlador tengo la función que me muestra la información:

```
   public function show ($id){

    $activo = DB::table('tb_activos as a')
    ->join('tb_ubicacion as u', 'a.id_act', '=', 'u.id_ubic')
    ->select('a.id_act', 'u.nombre', 'u.responsable' , 'a.num_serie', 'a.marca', 'a.modelo', 'a.estado', 'a.observaciones', 'a.año')
    ->where('a.id_act', '=', $id)
    ->first();
    return view ("inventario.activo.view", ["activo"=>Activo::findOrFail($id)]);
}
```

y en mi vista muestro en un input los valores asi:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_ubic">Ubicación del Activo</label>
                <input type="text" name="id_ubic" class="form-control" value="{{ $activo->ubicacion}}" disabled>
            </div>
```

Creo que el problema puede venir en el controlador con la funcion show, pero he probado de cambiar en el join y nada.

Comment: Tienes los modelos y las relaciones creadas?

Comment: Los modelos si, las relaciones solo en phpmyadmin...estoy siguiendo un manual y solo relacionan en phpmyadkin

Comment: Convendría que expliques mejor que tipo de relación hay entre las tablas y el resultado que buscas obtener, de esa forma alguiente podrá apoyar mostrándote como hacer la consulta con Eloquent

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo primero qje nada...la relación es de uno a uno, es decir que un activo tiene una ubicacion  establecida

Comment: ok, ahora ¿qué resultado es el que esperas obtener con la consulta?

Comment: Poder mostrar el nombre de esa ubicación en lugar del id...por ejemplo la ubicacion oficina tiene el id 1, el activo monitor esta asignado a la oficina, y al momento de rescatar la informacion del monitor quiero mostrar oficina en lugar del numero de id

Comment: Ok asi es mas claro, te respondo

Answer (score 1):

Primero vas a crear los modelos para cada tabla con el comando:

```
php artisan make:model Modelo
```

Donde modelo serán tanto:

- Activo para representar a la tabla `tb_activos`
- Ubicacion para representar a la tabla `tb_ubicacion`

Posterior en cada modelo vas a declarar las relaciones respectivas que identifican quien tiene uno y quien pertenece a uno; por medio de:

- hasOne
- belongsTo

Modelo Activo

```
  class Activo extends Model 
  {
    protected $table = 'tb_activos';

    public function ubicacion()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(Ubicacion::class);
    }
  }
```

Modelo Ubicacion

```
  class Ubicacion extends Model 
  {
    protected $table = 'tb_ubicacion';

    public function activo()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Activo::class);
    }
  }
```

En el controlador debes importar a la clase por medio de su namespace de esta forma:

```
use App\Activo;
```

La consulta podría ser de esta forma:

```
$data = Activo::whereHas('ubicacion', function($query) {
    $query->where('id_ubic', 1);
})->get();
```

Lo que hicimos fue indicarle:

- Obtén todos los datos del modelo Activo
- Donde tenga 1 relación existente con la tabla `tb_ubicacion` a través de la relación `ubicacion`
- Por dentro a esa relación la filtramos donde el `id_ubic` sea por ejemplo igual a 1
- Obtenemos la colección de registros por medio de `get()`